# Angular - how to set up click event on the start

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to append click event to all li (list) elements (I have ordered list - ul). I am using angular controller. Strange thing is that it doesnt work. Here's part of the code where I am setting this event (inside angular controller):

```
$document.ready(function () {

    $scope.GetAllNotes();
    $scope.AddSortable();
    $scope.SetEvents(); //function call to function with click event for li
    Loader.Hide();        
    $window.focus();        
})
```

Function with click event:

```
$scope.SetEvents = function () {

    jQuery("#ulNotes li").click(function () {
        alert("You've clicked li!");
    });
}
```

I guess if this doesn't work I can still use IIFE, but I believe there must be angular way to do this.

Comment: Try not to use jQuery at all. Use `ng-click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jQuery with Angular like Tushar stated.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="SampleController">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items"> <!-- assuming you're looping through a list' -->
        <li ng-click="clickFunction($index)">Click me!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyModule')
    .controller('SampleController', ControllerController);

ControllerController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function ControllerController($scope) {

    $scope.items = []; // your list of items

    $scope.clickFunction = function(index) {
        alert("You've clicked list item: " + index);
    }

}
})();
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the whole clicked element in angular? (like keyword this in jquery) ?

Comment: [Here's a guide for understanding $event](https://thinkster.io/egghead/index-event-log) keyword. You can pass the event to the function and then should be able to access the element that triggered it.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in an jQuery way, but in angular thinks are done different.

To add a simple click event to a list element you just have to add the `ng-click` directive (like mentioned in the comments) like this:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-click="myFn()"></li>
   <li ng-click="myFn()"></li>
   <li ng-click="myFn()"></li>
</ul>
```

I your controller you have to define something like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.myFn = function() {
});
```